# How can I change the value of Solana account with iterator?

Tags: rust, solana

I wanna implement the feature that allow user to vote and change account value.

Now I get the error below.

```
cannot move out of dereference of `anchor_lang::prelude::Account<'_, BaseAccount>`
move occurs because value has type `Vec<ItemStruct>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How can I change account value with iterator?
Here is the part of my code.

```
    pub fn vote(ctx: Context<Vote>, gif_id: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        let user = &mut ctx.accounts.user;

        let gif_iter = base_account.gif_list.into_iter(); // error occur here
        match gif_iter.find(|item| item.id == gif_id) {
            Some(gif) => gif.votes += 1,
            _ => (),
        }

        Ok(())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue myself.
I fixed function like below.

```
    pub fn vote(ctx: Context<Vote>, gif_id: u16) -> Result<()> {
        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;

        let gif_iter = &mut base_account.gif_list.iter_mut();
        gif_iter
            .find(|item| item.id == gif_id)
            .map(|found| found.votes += 1);

        Ok(())
    }
```

into_iter() function move ownership of account to new variable. So I got the error.
I replace it with iter_mut() function. And also replacing match with map.